# Ocra: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: ruby, ocra

I'm tweaking a project written in Ruby. I don't want the consumers of the tool having to install anything (such as Ruby itself) so I'm trying to compile the script into an exe file using ocra. However the compiled exe file fails with this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried using `--add-all-core` and `--gem-full` as those options looked like something that could help adding any missing libraries but it didn't help. How can I fix this?

Note: I've never worked with Ruby before so please try to be a bit more specific with the reply than you would for an experienced Ruby developer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `--add-all-core` doesn't work correctly. Had to use these:

```
  --dll "ruby_builtin_dlls\libssp-0.dll" \
  --dll "ruby_builtin_dlls\libgmp-10.dll" \
  --dll "ruby_builtin_dlls\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll" \
  --dll "ruby_builtin_dlls\libwinpthread-1.dll" \
```